# Mongoid equivalent of ActiveRecord's `serialize` method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, mongodb, mongoid

hope the title's pretty self-explanatory.

I'm using `mongoid` as my ORM for a Rails app, and I was wondering if anybody knew if it has an equivalent to ActiveRecord's [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize) method. I've looked through the mongoid documentation but haven't been able to find anything yet.

Here's an example of the model:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :params, type: String
  serialize :params            # method from ActiveRecord
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to serialize with MongoDB as far as you can store in fields Arrays and Hashes.

```
field :hash_params, type: Hash
field :array_params, type: Array
```

Comment: Thanks so much--can't believe I forgot about that (still used to sql). I'll accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need use the Value Object pattern and the same function like composed_of, some people wants to deprecate this function in the future and than you want to use `serialize` of standard active record. Mongoid provide the same functionality to create Value object avoid the `serialize` method look , you can provide your custom serialization here http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#custom_fields:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :params, type: String
  field :custom_params , type: MyCustomParamsType
end
```